# How to create pubsub topic with Customer-managed encryption key in JAVA

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to create Pub/Sub topic with customer-managed encryption keys in Java.

In Python we can create a topic using CMEK location as parameter as below:

```py
topic = client.create_topic(
    topic_path,
    kms_key_name=cmek_location,
    message_storage_policy=get_allowed_region()
)
```

In java I am using the following:

```java
TopicAdminClient topicAdminClient = TopicAdminClient.create(topicAdminSettings);
topicAdminClient.createTopic(topic);
```

How can we use the CMEK location in java code?

Comment: Please, can you provide your current python code?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: In Python we can create a topic using CMEK location as parameter as below,
topic = client.create_topic(topic_path, kms_key_name=cmek_location, message_storage_policy=get_allowed_region())

But in java i am using the below code,
TopicAdminClient topicAdminClient = TopicAdminClient.create(topicAdminSettings);
topicAdminClient.createTopic(topic);

How can we use the CMEK location in java code..?

Comment: Thank you @Krishna0696. I posted a possible answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that purpose you can use the following code, extracted from the `createTopic` method [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-pubsub/latest/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/TopicAdminClient.html#createTopic-com.google.pubsub.v1.Topic-):

```java
try (TopicAdminClient topicAdminClient = TopicAdminClient.create()) {
  Topic request =
    Topic.newBuilder()
        .setName(TopicName.ofProjectTopicName("[PROJECT]", "[TOPIC]").toString())
        .putAllLabels(new HashMap<String, String>())
        .setMessageStoragePolicy(MessageStoragePolicy.newBuilder().build())
        .setKmsKeyName("kmsKeyName412586233")
        .setSchemaSettings(SchemaSettings.newBuilder().build())
          .setSatisfiesPzs(true)
          .setMessageRetentionDuration(Duration.newBuilder().build())
          .build();
  Topic response = topicAdminClient.createTopic(request);
}
```

Basically you provide a template of the [`Topic`](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/be6a48fc83d15a320bc86a8b64dc55e66ad6ac11/proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1/src/main/java/com/google/pubsub/v1/Topic.java#L30) you want to create.

In your use case I suppose it will look like similar to this:

```java
try (TopicAdminClient topicAdminClient = TopicAdminClient.create()) {
  Topic request =
    Topic.newBuilder()
      .setName(TopicName.ofProjectTopicName("[PROJECT]", "[TOPIC]").toString())
      .setKmsKeyName("kmsKeyName412586233") //cmek location
      .setMessageStoragePolicy(
         MessageStoragePolicy.newBuilder()
           .addAllowedPersistenceRegions("us-central1") // get_allowed_region
           .build()
      )
      .build();
  Topic response = topicAdminClient.createTopic(request);
}
```

Please, pay attention to the `setKmsKeyName` method.

The API is described in this [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/create).

Comment: You are welcome @Krishna0696. I am happy to hear that it worked properly. Please, if you do not mind, and you consider it appropriate, can you mark the answer as correct? Thank you very much.